# Align multiple inline radio button groups with labels vertically (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, label, radio-group

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 15px;">
    <div style="margin: 8px 0 8px 5px;">
        <h3>Constitutional</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">Group 1.1:</label>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-wch-na" type="radio" name="ros-wch" value="na" checked />
                    <label for="ros-wch-na">N/A</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-wch-y" type="radio" name="ros-wch" value="y" />
                    <label for="ros-wch-y">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-wch-n" type="radio" name="ros-wch" value="n" />
                    <label for="ros-wch-n">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">Group 1.2:</label>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-an-na" type="radio" name="ros-an" value="na" checked />
                    <label for="ros-an-na">N/A</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-an-y" type="radio" name="ros-an" value="y" />
                    <label for="ros-an-y">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-an-n" type="radio" name="ros-an" value="n" />
                    <label for="ros-an-n">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">Row2 Group1:</label>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-ns-na" type="radio" name="ros-ns" value="na" checked />
                    <label for="ros-ns-na">N/A</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-ns-y" type="radio" name="ros-ns" value="y" />
                    <label for="ros-ns-y">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-ns-n" type="radio" name="ros-ns" value="n" />
                    <label for="ros-ns-n">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">Row2 Group2:</label>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-hc-na" type="radio" name="ros-hc" value="na" checked />
                    <label for="ros-hc-na">N/A</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-hc-an" type="radio" name="ros-hc" value="y" />
                    <label for="ros-hc-an">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input id="ros-hc-an" type="radio" name="ros-hc" value="n" />
                    <label for="ros-hc-n">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using [awesome-bootstrap-checkbox](https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox) for the radio buttons, so that's why the markup is a bit different and what the radio-* classes are for.

The goal here is to have them all line up vertically and horizontally. Horizontally is not a problem, that works fine. However, labels of different lengths cause the radio button groups to shift, and it becomes uneven, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY597.png). The desired effect is to have the radio groups align vertically and look even.

What would the proper CSS/HTML be so that the groups align both horizontally and vertically, no matter the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the `Label` part and `Radio-boxes` part into two. Have labels with fixed width and wrap the long labels.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class='labelsDiv'>
           <label class="radio-inline">Group 1.2:</label>
        </div>
        <div class='radiosDiv'>
            <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                <input id="ros-an-na" type="radio" name="ros-an" value="na" checked />
                <label for="ros-an-na">N/A</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                <input id="ros-an-y" type="radio" name="ros-an" value="y" />
                <label for="ros-an-y">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                <input id="ros-an-n" type="radio" name="ros-an" value="n" />
                <label for="ros-an-n">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a bunch mate.